# Is some code page or character set issue causing files to be modified in Git?

Tags: git, locale, codepages

Whenever I do a git pull after making some changes to a repo a certain set of files are always modified even when I haven't edited them.

The files are some `.po` files for Russian and I don't know if something about the locale or code page triggers the modification.#

Here is the output of `git diff` for the relevant files.

```
diff --git a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.es.po b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.es.po
index fa48381..1171ce8 100644
--- a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.es.po
+++ b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.es.po
@@ -75,8 +75,8 @@ msgstr "Campo '%s' no usado en expresión de filtro"

 #: rxdconst.sexprbadnulltest
 #, fuzzy
-#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
-msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
 msgstr "Valor nulo habilitado en '=' y '<>'"

 #: rxdconst.sexprexpected
diff --git a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.po b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.po
index 6686c7d..40b98c5 100644
--- a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.po
+++ b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.po
@@ -74,7 +74,7 @@ msgid "Field '%s' not used in filter expression"
 msgstr ""

 #: rxdconst.sexprbadnulltest
-msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
 msgstr ""

 #: rxdconst.sexprexpected
diff --git a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.ru.po b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.ru.po
index 38f3a8a..76ccdf6 100644
--- a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.ru.po
+++ b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.ru.po
@@ -75,8 +75,8 @@ msgstr "Поле '%s' не может быть использовано в вы

 #: rxdconst.sexprbadnulltest
 #, fuzzy
-#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
-msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
 msgstr "NULL-значения разрешены только в выражениях '=' и '<>'"

 #: rxdconst.sexprexpected
diff --git a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.uk.po b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.uk.po
index f479eba..b6fa70d 100644
--- a/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.uk.po
+++ b/rx2651/languages/rxdconst.uk.po
@@ -84,8 +84,8 @@ msgstr "Поле '%s' не може бути використане в вира

 #: rxdconst.sexprbadnulltest
 #, fuzzy
-#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
-msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+#| msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' и '<>'"
+msgid "NULL-values enabled in '=' Ð¸ '<>'"
 msgstr "NULL-значення дозволені тільки у виразах '=' і '<>'"

 #: rxdconst.sexprexpected
```

Comment: Is it UTF-8 encoded? Could it be that it ends up changing the characters to the whatever your font supports?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous How can I check if it is UTF-8 encoded? The bigger question is does Git perform some automatic conversion when it checks out the file?